# How to create a numeric vector of zero length in R

Tags: r, vector, numeric, zero

I wonder, how can I create a numeric zero-length vector in R?

Comment: I believe it is `numeric(0)`.

Comment: Do not forget to accept the answer if you liked it!

Answer (score 112):

If you read the help for `vector` (or `numeric` or `logical` or `character` or `integer` or `double`, 'raw' or `complex` etc   )  then you will see that they all have a `length` (or `length.out` argument which defaults to 0

Therefore

```
numeric()
logical()
character()
integer()
double()
raw()
complex() 
vector('numeric')
vector('character')
vector('integer')
vector('double')
vector('raw')
vector('complex')
```

All return 0 length vectors of the appropriate atomic modes.

```
# the following will also return objects with length 0
list()
expression()
vector('list')
vector('expression')
```

Comment: I apologize for the down vote; it was completely accidental and I only just noticed it had happened. It won't let me change. Sorry.

Comment: And if the empty vector is intended to hold dates, what would you use?

Comment: @Zelbinian That's a curiosity. What are you trying to achieve by doing that?

Answer (score 57):

Simply:

```
x <- vector(mode="numeric", length=0)
```

Answer (score 4):

Suppose you want to create a vector x whose length is zero. Now let v be any vector.

```
> v<-c(4,7,8)
> v
[1] 4 7 8
> x<-v[0]
> length(x)
[1] 0
```

Comment: I don't know what is happening there. Again my answer is mark down. Why??? I want to know explanation. Can anyone give me answer why my answer marks down?

Comment: You are taking the length of vector element.

Comment: Length is the proven that, the numeric  vector (here x) has zero length vector. And x vector is created from any other vector. So x is the desired vector of zero length. Also you should check the heading of the problem clearly? @ShaaradDalvi

Answer (score 3):

This isn't a very beautiful answer, but it's what I use to create zero-length vectors:

```
0[-1]     # numeric
""[-1]    # character
TRUE[-1]  # logical
0L[-1]    # integer
```

A literal is a vector of length 1, and `[-1]` removes the first element (the *only* element in this case) from the vector, leaving a vector with zero elements.

As a bonus, if you want a single `NA` of the respective type:

```
0[NA]     # numeric
""[NA]    # character
TRUE[NA]  # logical
0L[NA]    # integer
```